# Errors in printing

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

To show the printable document directly with out saving that file, I set the response header as "Content-Disposition","inline". Now it is showing the file but some times that file not being opened. It is showing some error messages like

1. "There was an error in opening this document. The file is damaged and can not be repaired"
2. "Adobe Reader cannot open this file. It might not be supported file type or that file was damaged".

and If click on print button again it working fine It is showing the document. So what I have to do to avoid those error messages. Can you please suggest me.

Thanks,
Vara Kumar

Comment: does your server have gzip compression enabled? make sure to turn it off during this session.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you build your stream of bytes on server. Those errors indicates truncated stream (=incomplete pdf) or extra data before or after the end of right content (=invalid pdf).